# how to define struct priv_struct of net_device?

Tags: linux-device-driver

When the device driver writer make up a driver, i notice that they use the function call `alloc_etherdev(sizeof(struct priv_struct))` to allocate an structure `struct net_device`.
my problem is about `struct priv_struct`.
I don't understand how they do to define it (`struct priv_struct`).
where they go from to make it?
Does it exists a documentation that explain how to define priv_struct for a device?
If it's yes where i can find a such document? thank.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. `priv_struct` is a name of a custom structure that holds all private data of the driver. `alloc_etherdev` wants to know it's size, and that's all. It's up to you to define this structure.

Kernel source code is huge, and it's impossible to document everything, so often the fastest way to resolve the issue is just to [look into the code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=alloc_etherdev) itself.